# alternative ways of saying "I sent that by accident"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I sent a message on Messenger to the wrong person, and I wanted to explain that the message was sent by mistake.

I figured I could just say "ooops I sent that by accident". but I wonder if there are other ways of saying this.

Comment: "I didn't mean to send that to you"

Comment: Amazingly, I can't find *any* dictionary support for the (admittedly, somewhat affected) usage ***Belay** [previous communication or instruction]*. But [here]() are some written instances in Google Books from which it's obvious the intended meaning is ***belay = ignore** [something said / written earlier]*. But I personally have sent "belay previous email" many times over the years, and I'd like to think the intended meaning would always have been understood.

Comment: Oops - belay reference to Google Books above (forgot to include the actual link! :) But [here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22belay+that+command%22) are many written instances of ***Belay that command** [which was erroneous, and should be ignored]*.

Comment: "Please ignore the message I just sent you" "Please ignore the message which I just sent you by mistake"

Comment: @FumbleFingers "belay" means "stop" or "cancel" (an order). It does not mean ignore, except in the sense of cancelling an order, which is not the context here

Comment: @gotube: I have access to the full (subscription-only) OED, which has no less than 17 separate definitions for the verb ***belay*** (plus a couple more for the *noun*). The word "cancel" doesn't occur anywhere in the definitions (the word "stop" occurs once in a *usage* citation, but there's no indication that this reflects the meaning of the word being defined). Admittedly, *most* of the OED's definitions are flagged "obsolete", but the fact of the matter is *none* of them suggest either "cancel" *or* "ignore". So like I said, no definitions tally with my understanding OR those GB examples.

Comment: ...also its seems obvious to me that *in OP's cited context*, the meanings ***cancel*** and ***ignore*** are both synonymous with my understanding of the word ***belay***, so I really don't understand *that* point.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interesting! My go-to dictionary is [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belay), and their second definition reads: *nautical* :  STOP CANCEL. I mostly use the word to mean "cancel" an order. I've never heard anyone use it to mean "ignore", except in the sense that asking someone to ignore an order is equivalent to cancelling it. To me, "belay that message" means "cancel/ignore the order to send that message".

Comment: @gotube: I usually look at M-W first too (OED is a bit more roundabout, because I have to actually log in to access it). I can only imagine I missed that second definition (with STOP, CANCEL in *capitals*, no less! :) because sometimes my eyes are a bit funny, and if I'm using the "page zoom" feature in my browser, I don't see that line unless I scroll down. But I certainly don't see that definition explicitly in the OED. Probably *on a ship*, "Belay that message" would be addressed to the radio man, and would indeed mean "Don't send it". But obviously that's nonsense in an SMS text context.

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to accomplish this, and your choice would depend on how familiar you are with this person.

For a close friend, you might say, "Sorry, wrong person."

In a more formal situation, you might say, "Sorry, that message was intended for someone else, please disregard."